# How to take item.get(id) from onclickLister of a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-studio

I have created an Activity where there are a main ListView  that is composed by a Item_layout(where there is 3 textview and 2 images) that is repeated several time.
I want, if someone click on an image of my ListView, that to do something.... I have tried to doing this, but It doesn't work:

```
ListView sectionedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SectionedListView);
sectionedListView.setAdapter(baseSectionedAdapter);
sectionedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     switch(view.getId())
      {
        case R.id.Dots:
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You click the 3 dots",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         break;
        }
}
});
```

EDIT (It Works!):
I have tried to modify my class BaseSelectionedAdapter where there is the method get View, this is the code and Now It Works =):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int rowType = getItemViewType(position);
    BaseModel model = (BaseModel) mData.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (rowType) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);

                holder.Container = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Item_Layout_Container);
                holder.MenuDots = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Dots);
                int r0=model.IsThereMenu();
                holder.MenuDots.setVisibility(r0);
                holder.MenuDots.setOnClickListener(mMyImageClickListener);

                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null);
                holder.Container = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleHeaderContainer);
                holder.Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleHeader);
                holder.myType = ViewHolderType.Header;
                break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.Title.setText(model.GetTitle());
    return convertView;
}
private View.OnClickListener mMyImageClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("Hello", "Hello");
    }
};
```

Comment: debug and check what's happening.

Comment: Then you need to set OnClickListener inside adapter instead of in `onItemClick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the listener to the Holder you are using in the adapter. Check this website http://scottweber.com/2013/04/30/adding-click-listeners-to-views-in-adapters/-

Code from the website:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_simple, parent, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        Button btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        holder = new ViewHolder(tv, btn);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.button.setTag(position);

    return convertView;
}

private static final int[] COLORS = new int[] { 0xffa00000, 0xff00a000, 0xff0000a0 };
private int mLastColor = 0;

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public Button button;

    public ViewHolder(TextView tv, Button btn) {
        text = tv;
        button = btn;
        button.setOnClickListener(mMyLocalClickListener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mMyLocalClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text.setColor(COLORS[mLastColor]);
            mLastColor = (mLastColor + 1) % COLORS.length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried what you have writed... but It doesn't work, when I try to click on an Item, but nothing appened... He never entry in the View.OnclickListener

Comment: @LizLamperouge add the code to the question, i will look into it.

Comment: You have 2 different layouts inside adapter are you using them in one listview? And you could remove setOnItemClickListener from listview and check then, but it seams that your code should work, I am not sure what else could there be. Add your layouts and row layouts, maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Yes, I am using 2 different layout, the first is the main layout that is composed by a menu layout, some text and by the item_layout. At the end   It go into the action View.OnClickListener mMyImageClickListener =)
Now I have other problem for the action that I want to do, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`onItemClick` function is provided with `View view` parameter as you were trying to use. This parameter however is `View`, which was returned from adapters `getView(..)` method.

So if you want to registr clicks on single Views from which is item composed, you need to use `View.OnClickListener` on every vies you want to handle separatly.

For example in you `Adapters` getView method you can assign onClick listener to every image or textview from which is your list item composed. Be carefull about setting your view in xml layout as `clickable="false"` `android:focusable="false"` in this case view won't get click event fired.